# Input value must be equal to some value in database

Tags: javascript, php, html, laravel

So i have this simple code to select value from database in registration form and it's work great

```
<div id="ref1" class="form-group form-material floating">
    <select class="form-control" name="reference" id="reference">
      @foreach (App\Models\Reference::getReference() as $key => $value)
        <option value="" selected disabled hidden></option>
        <option value="{{$value->id}}">{{$value->reference}}</option>
      @endforeach
    </select>
    <label class="floating-label" for="inputStatus">Reference</label>
</div>
```

But i want to change this into input field, so when user type it manually and it's not having the same value in the database, the registration will fail (Error Message : 'Wrong reference code'), does anyone have and idea how to do it? Thanks

Edit 1 :
I also have this validation code for the reference

```
reference: {
            validators: {
                notEmpty: {
                    message: 'Reference must be filled'
                },
                stringLength: {
                    max: 8,
                    message: 'Reference maximal 8 digit'
                }
            }
        }
```

Can i also use exists rule on that validator?

Comment: but isn't that what the select box is supposed to prevent? instead of manually typing any invalid value, you provide the user with the valid values? but anyways, you can use a combox box instead. plus you should be validating the value if thats the case, just use the answer below laravel wise

Comment: Yes i know that, but the client want it to be inputted manually, combo box .. i will try it Thanks @Kevin!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done by creating custom `Laravel Request` validation. If your reference is stored in database, you can check if the input value exists in database, after the form is submitted by using `exists` rule. Here's a simple example:

```
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'field_name' => 'exists:your_table_name', //Table name where reference is stored
        ];
    }
    public function messages()
    {
        return [
            'field_name.exists' => 'Wrong reference code',
        ];
    }
```

You can read more on official [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#rule-exists).